# how fetch custom news from one domain to another domain in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi we have a group website say www.group-school.com and in this having many schools for eg. www.school-matric.com, www.school-cbse.com, www.school-hss.com

we have seperate news page for each school ( www.school-matric.com, www.school-cbse.com, www.school-hss.com )

That will be displayed in front page of each schools website by following code

```
<?php 
    query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post_type' => 'news', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
    endwhile;

    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The Question:
  I want to dispaly news in group site (www.group-school) that was posted in each website ( www.school-matric.com, www.school-cbse.com, www.school-hss.com ).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, you can use the RSS feed for the latest news on each site and populate your group site with the news.